# WebServiceContext is null in Apache cxf Web services

Tags: java, web-services, resources, cxf

I'm trying to set the context of a CXF Apache web service by using the @Resource annotation. But the context always comes as null. Please help to overcome this problem. Below is the webservice which I'm trying to access the messageContext.

```
@WebService(serviceName = "RequestManagerService", targetNamespace = IRMNamespaces.WSDL+IRMVersions.WSDL_VERSION)
@Addressing(enabled=true, required=true)
public class RequestManager implements IRequestManager{

@Resource
WebServiceContext context;

@WebMethod(action = IRMNamespaces.WSDL+IRMVersions.WSDL_VERSION+"/RequestManagerService/SubscriberStateChangeRequest", operationName = "subscriberStateChange")
@Oneway
public void subscriberStateChangeRequest(
        @WebParam(partName = "subscriberStateChangeRequest", name = "subscriberStateChangeRequest", targetNamespace = IRMNamespaces.SERVICE+IRMVersions.WSDL_VERSION) SubscriberStateChangeRequestType subscriberStateChangeRequest) {
    MessageContext ctx = context.getMessageContext();
```

Below is the configuration part which regarding to above web service.

```
<bean id="rmService" class="com.morpho.rm.core.base.process.service.RequestManager">
</bean>
<jaxws:endpoint id="RequestMangerIntf" 
    implementor="#rmService"
    address="/RequestManager">
    <jaxws:binding><soap:soapBinding version="1.2" mtomEnabled="false"/></jaxws:binding>

    <jaxws:features> 
        <wsa:addressing xmlns:wsa="http://cxf.apache.org/ws/addressing" />
    </jaxws:features>
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Please help if anyone knows anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Setter Method on you WS Implementation.

If you want set parameter in message context you must set scope application for parameter.

The Default Scope is Handler not visible in WS Implementation

SoapHandler

```
 public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {

 smc.put("ID_MESSAGGIO",message.getId());
 smc.setScope("ID_MESSAGGIO", MessageContext.Scope.APPLICATION);

}
```

WS Implementation

```
   WebServiceContext context;

    @Resource
    public void setContext(WebServiceContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }



    @Override
    public CreateAndStartRequestByValueResponse   createAndStartRequestByValue(CreateAndStartRequestByValueRequest parameters) throws CreateAndStartRequestByValueException {

        MessageContext messageContext = context.getMessageContext();

        Long theValue = (Long) messageContext.get("ID_MESSAGGIO");
        return controller.startCreateAndStartRequestByValue(parameters);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using annotated WebServiceContext, just create new instance whenever required.

```
    WebServiceContext wsctx = new WebServiceContextImpl()
```